# tlmgr failed (lack of space?)

Tags: tlmgr, update

I tried `tlmgr update -all` and it reached `177/509 jadetex` then failed on `japanese-otf-uptex` (due to lack of space?). I deleted some (non-TeX) files to increase the available space and tried again. This time it reached `76/324` but failed on `76/324 montserrat`.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with `tlmgr` or my computer setup. I'm running Ubuntu under Windows (don't ask me why but it was the only way to use Ubuntu as I loathe Windows which came with the computer). I expect that I will never want to process Japanese documents (or probably no non-Engslish/USA documents). Can I eliminate TeX classes/packages for non-English documents from the TeXlive installation to free up space; if so, how? Or is there something else that I can do? (I'm in the UK and my grandchildren are in Canada so I can't expect any help from them).  GOM.

Comment: How much space do you actually have on the partition you use to install TL?

Comment: It could be a problem with the `/tmp` volume being allocated too little space.

Comment: @Werner  Total space 272.2 GB (used 140.8GB available 131.4GB)

Comment: @egreg `/tmp` has usage 0% and size 372.7kB

Comment: Those 131Gb available, is that seen from Linux, or from windows? On Linux you can run `df -h` to gt an idea of what kind of sizes you have on the system.

Comment: If you run it again, does it continue on to some other random completions? If that's the case, the problem might not be with you.

Comment: @daleif The 131GB is from Linux. I used the `Disk Usage Analyzer` to get the result.

Comment: Is `/tmp` a partition and if so how large is it? (running `df -h` in a terminal is much faster then the analyser it also shows what are partitions and what is not).

Comment: This also makes me wonder how you are running Ubuntu under Windows. I do so on my laptop (under VirtualBox). My disk on the linux side is not that large though. I don't use the laptop that often

Comment: I don't want to fiddle with the Ubuntu space allocations as I have a fear that might result in Ubuntu disappearing. Deleting stuff (classes/packages) from the TeXlive area seems a safer way to go for me.

Comment: I'm thinking that this might be a resource allocation issue then in Ubuntu "under windows". I would still like to see the results of `df -h` just to see if it looks different than a normal Ubuntu.

Comment: @daleif Running Ubuntu under Windows. I can't remember how I did it but I think tried to create to create a partition in which I could install Ubuntu. That didn't work. However I got a CD from *Beginning Ubuntu Linux* by Emilio Raggi et al that stuffed Ubuntu under Windows. I find computer systems very delicate and if I've got them to work I'm very reluctant to change anything. It is an old version of Ubuntu as I have been very reluctant to upgrade (it does what I want).

Comment: Nowadays running a dual boot isn't much worth it, and can be difficult because of secure boot etc. So IMO virtualization is a lot easier. That's how I run Windows at work. By base system is Ubuntu 18.04 and I can run a virtualized Win10 when I need to. My interest in the output of `df -h` is to see if the file system reported back is similar or different than a normal Ubuntu). It might be that you have a separate /tmp partition in Ubuntu that is very small, but a large /home partition, and thus a solution could be to set TMPDIR (or what ever tmpgr reacts to) to something with more space.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to update :) ...but it's necessary, for the moment you can check `/usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/backups` and remove what's there. If you have win10 you can install `WSL` and run what you need from ubuntu.

Comment: @daleif I have run `df -h` with the results (which I hope you can interpret: `/dev/loop0 29G 28G 18M 100% /` and `udev 1.5G 4.0K 1.5G 1% /dev` and `tmpfs 300M 836K 299M 1% /run` and `none 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock` and `none 1.5G 696K 1.5G 1% /run/shm` and `/dev/sda3 225G 105G 121G 47% /host`.  Elsewhere `texlive` is reported to be 100% full at 15.4G with `2018` taking 7.7G and `2019` taking 7.6G and `texmf-local` taking 45.5M. I suppose the question is: How do I increase `texlive`?

Comment: It is a rather strange file system, so sadly I cannot really help here. It would be interesting to know if `/host` is usable by Linux or if it is the host Windows system.

Comment: @daleif I think that we have to give up on this. Windows itself failed about a year ago and I'm now seriously considering getting a new PC just running Linux. Thanks to everybody for their help.

Comment: @PeterWilson might be a good idea, the current setup seems "strange" and thus not many can help.